# Empty Global Cache (Not Just the Application-Specific Cache)

Tags: android, caching

I see tons of apps for Android that allow you to "clear" the cache completely. I would like to implement the same functionality in my app.

I am familiar with `context.getCacheDir()` but this only returns the application-specific cache dir. Is there a way to recursively go through the cache directories of other apps as well and clear those?

On a side note, I would like to get the total cache files size, if that is possible at all.

Comment: None of this is available in the Android SDK.

Comment: this kind of stuff can only be accomplished on rooted devices.

Comment: Well, if you look at the application "com.rootuninstaller.rambooster" in the Google Play marketplace, it does precisely this without the need of root.